# How to obtain application context from broadcast receiver?

Tags: android

I have an extension of the Application class that I need to obtain reference in a BroadcastReceiver I have created. The context passed into the "onReceive" is a restricted context. Is there a way to obtain reference to the actual application context?

Comment: What makes you say that it is restricted. What specifically are you trying to do with the context?

Comment: Because the actual class of the context for the onReceive is of type ReceiverRestrictedContext. I have an extension of the Application that allows me to non-statically obtain reference to several objects I need.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Call `getApplicationContext()` on the `Context` supplied to you in `onReceive()`, just as you would call `getApplicationContext()` on an `Activity`.

> I have an extension of the Application that allows me to non-statically obtain reference to several objects I need.

While syntactically `Application` is not static, it has the same impact, particularly with respect to memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out at soon as I can to respond to your answer.

Comment: That worked thank you. I swore I tried that already but I guess I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

BroadcastReceiver already gives the context. Look at the onReceive.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class SMSReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val smsIntent = intent ?: return
        val appContext = context?.applicationContext ?: return
        // Do something here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually this is a RecieverRestrictedContext, not strictly speaking THE application context...