# Unable to display Toast message from inside onTick of a CountDownTimer (running inside the Service)

Tags: android, handler, toast, countdowntimer

I am trying to display a Toast message from inside onTick() function of a CountDownTimer class. This class is running inside a service.

Simple doing Toast.maketext("tag", "toast message") - crashes the application.

So I tried a handler - With the handler, app does not crash but I do not see a toast message either.  Any help on what is wrong will be helpful.

I am sure that my countdown timer is running properly and onTick is being called - i have added LogCat statements to confirm that.

```
public class MyServicelockCountdownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    public FBServicelockCountdownTimer(long millisInFuture,
            long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    "This is toast message from inside onTick of the CountDownTimer inside the Service",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                } else {

                }
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume your handler is created attached to the main thread looper?

Comment: Did you bind your service to your activity? http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger

Comment: check this thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319340/how-to-obtain-application-context-from-broadcast-receiver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `this` from your Activity instead of using getApplicationContext():

```
Toast.makeText(
    YourActivity.this,
    "This is toast message from inside onTick of the CountDownTimer inside the Service",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: This is inside a service, not an activity

Comment: try this link may be it may help you   [http://www.jjoe64.com/2011/09/show-toast-notification-from-service.html]

Comment: link is not functional

Answer (score 0):

Try using getMainLooper() method of Looper class which -

Returns the application's main looper, which lives in the main thread of the application. // from android docs.

And you should also consider binding Activites to services in order to handle UI updates.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942083/updating-ui-from-a-service-using-a-handler) as well for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent)
```

in onReceive you will context

Call getApplicationContext() on the Context supplied to you in onReceive(), just as you would call getApplicationContext() on an Activity.

Comment: I dont have an onReceive