# Sharedpreferences not accessable when activity started from broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences

(Slightly different issue to the other one I just posted, apologies if this is against the rules)

In my activity1 I am setting some shared preferences, next I start another activity2 via an intent and set some textviews from the `sharedpreferences` ... this all works fine.

Heres my problem.
In my first activity1, I have an `alarmmanger` with a pending intent, this pending intent is a broadcastreceiver used to lock the phone, then start activity2. This activity is the same second activity mentioned above. However, when this activity is started from the `broadcastreceiver`, none of the textviews have loaded from `sharedpreferences`. This only happens when starting activity2 from the `broadcastreceiver`.

`SharedPreference` are set in activity one as

```
SharedPreferences lockPreferences = getSharedPreferences("lockprefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

The are accessed in activity2 the same way

```
SharedPreferences lockPreferences = getSharedPreferences("lockprefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

I can then getString etc

When activity2 is started from the broadcastreceiver, none of the sharedprefs have loaded.

the `broadcastreceiver` is in a different package name, I moved it into the same package as the activities for testing but it made no difference.

Its driving me insane, please help!
Thanks

EDIT

I have a GCMIntentService, this is where I am setting the shared prefs (based on values received from a GCM) ( I have only included relevant code)

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

public static final String PREFERENCE_NAME = "lockPreference";

  @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        SharedPreferences lockPreference = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor lockPrefsEditor;
        lockPrefsEditor = lockPreference.edit();

lockPrefsEditor.putString("newpassword", newpassword);
lockPrefsEditor.commit();
```

Now if I start activity2 , the shared prefs are read correctly.
Its not working when trying to access from a broadcastreceiver first though.

This is a test **Receiver** :

```
package com.myapp;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class test extends BroadcastReceiver {


    public static final String TAG = "myapp";
    public static String newpassword = ""; 


 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


      Log.i(TAG,"test receiver");

      SharedPreferences lockPreference = context.getSharedPreferences(GcmIntentService.PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      newpassword = lockPreference.getString("newpassword", "");
      Log.i(TAG, "Password from shared prefs: " + newpassword);

      Toast.makeText(context, "Sharedprefs password:" + newpassword, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
}
```

The toast just displays Sharedprefs password:

This is the **activity2** , which can read the prefs no problem

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity  {


    String newpassword;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.set);


        //retrieve shared prefs
        SharedPreferences lockPreference = getSharedPreferences(GcmIntentService.PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
newpassword = lockPreference.getString("newpassword", "");
```

I can then make a `toast` or whatever.

I dont see why its failing for the broadcast receiver, is it not the same context ??

Comment: pasted and removed the code? is it solved?

Comment: pls show code from all places you try to access the SharedPreferences from - the BroadcastReceiver code is obviously debug code, but you don't show the Activity2 code in context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should know that the `SharedPreference` file you create by the method `getSharedPreference` is represented as a real `XML` file in you app directory, so if you already added your values and commit your modifications then all your edits should be exist.

Second, having a `BroadcastReceiver` class in your project should take the same `PackageName` of your project even if it was started while your app was closed.

Now all what you have to make sure of is the following:

1)Both `Activities` use the same `SharedPReference` file by create a `public` `constant` in your application that hold the file name.

```
public final static String PREFERENCE_NAME = "com.example.mypackage.preference"
```

2)Both `Activities` use the same `SharedPReference` file as following

```
SharedPreferences lockPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

3)Make sure that your edits are commited before the other file try to read it.

```
lockPreferences.putBoolean(CONSTANT_KEY, true);
commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I added a public constant but its still not working

Comment: Don't say it doesn't work. Always say the exception that you have got or the line that you have problem with. If you are using the preferences as I mentioned correctly,  you will not have any problem

Comment: There is no exception, so its proving difficult to trouble shoot ... I have edited above to show my testing

Comment: Dont ask me how but cleaned the project and it works now after adding the public constant ... thanks to all

Comment: I believe you if you are using Eclipse :). @Gary and Please if you have found my answer useful don`t forget to vote it up :) thnx

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what [Adb El-Rahman said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22119503/383414), the `SharedPreferences` are loaded from the XML file based on the `context` that you use.

As you can see, you are using the context passed into the `BroadcastReceiver`, which may not be the context of your app - so a different preferences file will be referenced. It is going to be a `ReceiverRestrictedContext` instance.

However, according to [@CommonsWare's answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11320028/383414), you should be able to get it working by calling `context.getApplicationContext()` inside your `BroadcastReceiver`.

---

As an aside, you should be careful of not running too much code inside a `BroadcastReceiver` - it seems the system does not like that.

Comment: how can I know if context is correct or not ? I simply specified context.getSharedPreferences ... this works in activity2 but not the broadcastreceiver

Comment: in the javadoc for `BroadcastReceiver`, it defines the context as "The Context in which the receiver is running." I think that means it can be the app that made the broadcast, and not your app. But an `Activity` is a `Context`, which is linked to your app. So basically don't put this code into a BroadcastReceiver, rather into an Activity or Service. Keep your BroadcastReceiver code really short and simple to avoid problems.

Comment: @Gary I found a related issue that suggests you should be able to access your `SharedPreferences` from your receiver. I still think it is a bad idea in production, but I can see you are trying some basic debugging. Interested to know if you can get that to work using `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: Yes , its working now thanks ... I am not doing much in the receiver, but I needed to set 1 or 2 values from sharedprefs.... all working now :-)